# DRYing up Rails error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

I have a Rails app which is part of a larger web site. I'd like to have a single 404 error page that's used consistently across the site. Currently I have a static page that's part of the landing site, which for historical reasons is served from the `public` section of the Rails app:

```
public/landing/404.html
```

Now I'd like my Rails app to serve that page in case of a 404 error. The approach I've tried is adapted from [this blog post](http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/08/19/redirecting-to-custom-404-and-500-pages-in-rails/):

```
config/application.rb:
  config.exceptions_app = self.routes

config/routes.rb:
  match '/404', to: redirect('/landing/404'), via: :all
```

This appears to work, in that a 404 error will deliver the `landing/404.html` page to the user agent that made the request. However, it delivers the page with status 200, because the server successfully redirected to the static page. So, not web standards compliant (and not very RESTful!).

My question is: can I serve the static page but with a 404 response code? Or is there a better way to DRY up my error page config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in `application_controller.rb`:

`unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
end`

Here, as you can guess, you can catch any type of exceptions you are interested in (`ActionController::RoutingError`, `ActionController::UnknownController`, or generally `Exception`), and it will only redirect in production, whereas in development it will show real exception.

```
def render_404
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render( layout: false, file: Rails.root.join( 'public', 'landing', status.to_s ), status: status ) }
    format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
  end
end
```

and leave `routes.rb` as it is.

Comment: Thanks. I had to make one change: `template: '/landing/404'` meant that Rails was looking in my views hierarchy for the a 404 template, which isn't where it is. I used instead: `format.html { render( layout: false, file: Rails.root.join( 'public', 'landing', status.to_s ), status: status ) }`